# filter doesnt show on homepage

Tags: magento-1.9, layered-navigation

ive followed these instructions and added this code to my layout XML on the homepage:

```
<reference name="left">
    <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

I also have added this to the homepage:

```
<reference name="left">
    <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

[DEMO URL](http://www.avfdevelopments.org/ecommerce/index.php/)

yet it still doesnt add filter to the homepage?
many thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 2):

Are you definitely rendering the `left` section on your homepage? Check this and if not.....

add this `<block type="catalog/layer_view" name="filter" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>` in your local.xml where you want it and
make sure you're calling it using `echo $this->getChildHtml('catalog.leftnav')` in the relevant section.

If the filters are only set to `filter with results` it probably won't show because there may be no products on the homepage?

You could also try `<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/layer_view')->setTemplate('catalog/layer/view.phtml')->toHtml() ?>`

Or from a cms block `{{block type="catalog/layer_view" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"}}`

Comment: how can i check that the left section is definately rendering - it works fine on the actual category pages not the homepage.

Comment: If you've got a cms block loading on the home page use the last option in the answer, if you know of a file that definitely gets rendered on the page add the second last option. You should really be doing all of this through a `local.xml` file with a page specific layout for the homepage and use the very first option in the answer though.

Comment: I really dont want to start coding things, basically this page looks awesome now and how want: http://www.avfdevelopments.org/ecommerce/index.php/sub.html and then this page... needs to look the same! http://www.avfdevelopments.org/ecommerce/index.php/

Comment: mate what i said in the last comment could hardly be considered coding. Either way you're gonna have to render the filters through something that loads on your homepage.

Comment: it doesnt seem like ANYTHING out of the layout Update XML is rendering on the homepage - just removed all of it and the page still shows the same!

Comment: you're best bet is to turn on template hints from `system -> configuration` - `developer` - `template hints` and that will show you the paths to the files getting rendered. Then you will know what you need to edit. The issue sounds to me more like not knowing what actually makes up your homepage than how to add a template.

Comment: having looked at your links it would seem as though you're trying to turn your homepage into a category page. You could just set the homepage to redirect to a page of your choice from the admin if you really want to avoid coding anything